# Cookie with "expires" not sent with JSONP request in IE

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, jsonp

It's needed to set 'token' cookie on domain A same as already set on domain B.
We use JSONP crossdomain request to pass cookie from domain B to domain A.
JQuery code on domain A looks like

```
var url = "http://domain.com/get_token.php?jsonpcallback=?";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonpCallback: "",
    data: {'domain': "<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>"}
});
```

get_token.php on domain B looks like

```
<?php
    header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
    $cookie=$_COOKIE['token'];
    echo 'var token = "'.$cookie.'";
          var domain = "'.$_GET['domain'].'";
          if(token!="") {
            var cookie_params = {
               path    : "/",
               domain  : domain,
                   expires: 30
                };
            $.cookie("token", token, cookie_params);
           }';
?>
```

Everything works fine in all browsers except IE. I've tried to set different P3P headers but it doesn't help. I've also tried to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, but no result. What only helps is manually setting Privacy Setting in IE to "Accept All Cookies".

The cookie I need to get has "expires" property. What is interesting is that IE sends cookies without "expires" property, but cookies with that property are not sent.

Is it possible to get the cookie without manual changing IE privace settings?

Comment: What if you send no P3P header at all? Also, why do you need to exchange cookie data? Should this data maybe not be in a cookie?

Comment: @Doge , without P3P header cookie also is not sent. I need to get token that is stored only in cookie on another domain.